# How can I add fonts in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add different fonts in the Android Studio. Actually, I have already added the font family in the Android but when I use the font family in code it gives me an error.

I want to add fonts in the Android Studio and just want to learn how to add more fonts in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

To add fonts as resources, perform the following steps in Android Studio:

- Right-click the res folder and go to New > Android resource directory. The New Resource Directory window appears.
- In the Resource type list, select font, then click OK
  Add your font files in the font folder.
- The folder structure below generates R.font.dancing_script, R.font.lobster, and R.font.typo_graphica.
- Double-click a font file to preview the file's fonts in the editor

Note: The name of the resource directory must be font.

Answer (score 1):

you could use default font in android studio like this:

1. click Resource Manager (leftmost of android studio)
2. find "Font" tab, if it not visible, click more button
3. click (+) button and choose 'More Fonts...'
4. choose or search font

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fonts as resources, please perform the following steps in Android Studio:

Create a folder named font inside the **res** folder and copy your font.

Font names can only consist of lowercase letters a-z, numbers 0-9, or underscore.

[image]

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_bold" />
```